# onChange is not invoked when dropdown menu has only 1 item

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs

I am populating my dropdown menu dynamically and I sometimes end up with having a single element in the dropdown. For multiple elements, there is no problem, the `onChange()` of my select tag works perfect. However, when there is only 1 element, the `onChange()` does not invoke. How can I solve this problem? Thank you!

```
getOptions(){
    var dynamicOptions = this.props.something
    const returnedOptions = []
    for(int i=0; i< dynamicOptions.length;i++){
          returnedOptions.push(<option value = {dynamicOptions[i]}>something</option>
    }
    return dynamicOptions;
}

return(
    <select onChange=this.onchangemethod, value = {something}>
    {this.getOptions()}
    </select>
)
```

Comment: Just check dynamicoptions is array, when 1 items come in your value

Comment: What exactly is the issue?  If there's only one option then the user can't "change" the selection.  If it's selected by default, can't be changed, and can't be de-selected then you know which of the *one* options available was "selected".

Comment: @David in my onChange() function I am setting a variable to send to my backend and this variable's value must be the selected option. So, if there is only one option my backend gets an empty string rather than the only available option.

Comment: @Kamadan: If there's only one option then why can't you send that option to the back-end by default instead of relying on the user's selection?  Again, if you have a UI where the user *can't change the selection* then you know what the selection is.  What's stopping you from inferring that selection?

Comment: Why are you using `int` to declare a variable in JavaScript? I'm questioning myself how is that code working for you. For that case it would be better to use `let`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You would be having the same problem if the user would like to select the first option of many, since it would be the already selected one and the user would not need to re-select it.

One workaround is to always specify an "empty" option with a placeholder text

```
<select onChange={this.onchangemethod}>
  <option value="">Please choose an option</option>
  {this.getOptions()}
</select>
```

This way, you will always have at least two options, and the user will have to open and select one.

---

An alternative is to pre-select the first option so that, again, in case of user inaction, there is one option selected.

```
for(int i=0; i < dynamicOptions.length; i++) {
  const optionProperties = {value: dynamicOptions[i]};
  if (i === 0) { optionProperties.selected: true };
  returnedOptions.push(<option {...optionProperties}>something</option>);
}
```